# Color by category - plotly scattermapbox

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I am trying to group the points on the map by category as determined by the column in the Pandas data frame. The code below uses plotly and Dash framework to build map layout and plot coordinates.

```
for i, row in Comp_data.groupby('Group'):

    data.append({
                "type": "scattermapbox",
                "lat": [hlat],
                "lon": [hlong],
                "name": "Location",
                "mode": "markers",
                "marker": {
                    "symbol": "circle",
                    "color": "grey", <-- needs to be dynamic based on the group
                    "size": 6,
                    "opacity": 0.7
                    }
                }

    )
```

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try to leave out the `color` property. The graph will give each data set another color.

```
"marker": {
    "symbol": "circle",
    "size": 6,
    "opacity": 0.7
}
```